# How to create a new raw in sqlite database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Table in sqlite and there is a auto increment field for ID name of field is "profile_id".

now I want to add a new row without any data except profile_id, and I need the value of "profile_id" of newly created row, Than what should my query, please suggest me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do an insert with empty values. Insert command returns id:
long id = db.insert(...);